# Sphinx ImportError for subdirectory import module from parent directory

Tags: python, html, makefile, python-sphinx, importerror

I'm quite new here. Was googling around and couldn'f find any answers on my problem.

I am trying to create a documentation using sphinx with the extension "sphinx.ext.autodoc". The sphinx documentation and the source code are completely separated. Therefore the path for 'myproject' and 'subdir' are include in the sys.path in the conf.py for sphinx.

Now I try to use the following import in 'moduleB.py' : from myproject.moduleA import myClass

The result, when I run 'make html' is an ImportError: No module named myproject.moduleA.

myproject

```
├── __init__.py
├── moduleA.py
└── subdir
    ├── __init__.py
    └── moduleB.py
```

Hopefully someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out by myself :D
To reference myproject.moduleA the parent directory for myproject (..) has also to be in the sys.path.
And I only had myproject and the subdir in my sys.path :/